# using Moq to verify a CommandHandler method call with correct Command Parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following test case:

```
    [Test]
    public void MarkAsSuccessfulTest()
    {
        //setup data
        var payment = Util.DbUtil.CreateNewRecurringProfilePayment();

        //unit test

        var mockNotificationSender = new Mock<IMarkAsSuccessfulNotificationSender>();
        var mockCommandHandler = new Mock<IDbCommandHandler<RecurringPaymentMarkAsSuccessfulCommand>>();

        var classUnderTest = new RecurringProfileMarkLastPaymentAsSuccessful(mockCommandHandler.Object, mockNotificationSender.Object);

        classUnderTest.MarkAsSuccessful(payment.RecurringProfile);
        mockCommandHandler.Verify(x=>x.Handle(It.IsAny<RecurringPaymentMarkAsSuccessfulCommand>()), Times.Once());
        mockNotificationSender.Verify(x=>x.SendNotification(payment), Times.Once());

    }
```

The issue is with the line:

```
mockCommandHandler.Verify(x=>x.Handle(It.IsAny<RecurringPaymentMarkAsSuccessfulCommand>()), Times.Once())
```

This verifies that the `.Handle()` method was called. However, this is not enough for the test - This `.Handle()` takes a command parameter, which has one property - `Payment`.  I would like to verify that this parameter was actually matching the `payment` variable.

Is this possible, or is there an issue with some of the code-design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide predicate for parameter verification:

```
mockCommandHandler.Verify(x => 
   x.Handle(It.Is<RecurringPaymentMarkAsSuccessfulCommand>(c => c.Payment == payment))
   , Times.Once());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using It.IsAny(). You can use It.Is()... something like the following:

```
mockCommandHandler.Verify(x => x.Handle(It.Is<RecurringPaymentMarkAsSuccessfulCommand>(command => command.Payment == payment)), Times.Once());
```

You can use It.Is() to check certain conditions on the argument being passed in. If it is literally the same reference, you can just follow what you are doing with your second verification, and instead change your code to the following:

```
mockCommandHandler.Verify(x => x.Handle(payment), Times.Once());
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer, and it seems all answers were posted almost at the same time - Unfortunately cannot mark as answer all of them, so had to mark the first one shown here! Thanks :)